# Filtering results for std away from the mean

Tags: python, pandas

I been trying to filter the results for std away from the mean in the most efficient manner

DF

```
 Cashier# Store Sales_ct Refunds_ct   
 001      001   100      10
 002      001   200      9
 003      001   900      8
 004      002   200      10
 005      002   400      9 
 006      002   200      8
```

How to get the results that are 2 std away from the mean to return

```
 Cashier# Store Sales_ct Refunds_ct  sales_std_away_mean 
 003      001   900      8
```

Comment: what does xyz std away from the mean mean? std is the standard deviation or sample standard deviation? Which value are you even referring to? Sales or Refunds or what?
What's the expected output? I assume it's not a DF with an extra empty column (like you show)?

Comment: What is xyz? Can you explain a bit more? Away from the mean of what?

Comment: thanks for your comments @joooeey , i added an edit to the post

Answer (score 3):

```
def abs_z(s):
    return s.sub(s.mean()).div(s.std(ddof=0)).abs()

df[abs_z(df.Sales_ct).ge(2)]

   Cashier#  Store  Sales_ct  Refunds_ct
2         3      1       900           8
```

Answer (score 2):

Can calculate the mean and std of the Sales_ct column with

```
sales_mean = np.mean(df.Sales_ct)
sales_std = np.std(df.Sales_ct)
```

Then make a new column as you noted

```
df['sales_std_away_mean'] = np.abs((df.Sales_ct - sales_mean)/sales_std)
```

Then slice to select the rows above a threshold:

```
subdf = df[df.sales_std_away_mean > 2.]
```